# Is the Promise returned in Angular's $http the same as one in vanilla Javascript (ES6)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, ecmascript-6, angular-promise

Just a newbie question on Promises and Angular...

When using AngularJS's `$http` to do a PUT or a POST and a `Promise` is returned

which is this `Promise {$$state: Object}` in the chrome console - is this the same kind of Promise that I could resolve without using the `.success(function(){...}).error(function(){...});` listed in the [Angular Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)?

I've just started to look into ES6 and decided to write this app using Babel ( which may or may not matter to the question ).
Basically I came across this as I was trying to call Controller function within a success callback.
Here is a snippet of my code:

```
class AuthController {
constructor ($timeout, $state, $http, apiService) {
    'ngInject';

    this.$http = $http;
    this.$state = $state;
    this.apiService = apiService;
}

setToken (user) {
    // set the token
}   

login () {
    var req = {
     method: 'PUT',
     url: this.apiService.apiHost + '/customers/login',
     headers: {
       'Authorization': undefined
     },
     data: { email: this.email, password: this.password }
    }
    this.$http(req)
    .success(function(data){
      this.setToken();
    })
    .error(function(data){
      // handle it
    });
```

However though, the `this` inside the `.success` block is actually `Window` !(!?)
How can I call my AuthController class's `setToken()` function inside this? 
Should I use a normal Javascript Promise? will the scope be different then?

What should I do to handle the promise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a `this` reference problem. But to answer your original question, Angular's `$http` returns a `$q` promise, which is different from ES6's promise.

Check out @atinder's solution for fixing your problem, or you can also use [arrow functions](https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/#arrows):

```
   var req = {
     method: 'PUT',
     url: this.apiService.apiHost + '/customers/login',
     headers: {
       'Authorization': undefined
     },
     data: { email: this.email, password: this.password }
    }
    this.$http(req)
    .success((data) => {
      this.setToken();
    })
    .error((data) => {
      // handle it
    });
```

Comment: Thanks so much man! It worked :) I'm lovin' those arrow functions now haha

Answer (score 0):

in order to have this available inside callback function you need to [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) it to the function like so.

```
.success(function(data){
  this.setToken();
}.bind(this));
```

another way could be assigning this to some other variable like so

```
var self = this;
```

then inside your callback

```
.success(function(data){
  self.setToken();
});
```